# Voltage divider with a potentiometer

Tags: voltage

[image]

I am trying to build a voltage divider as shown in the circuit.

I want to adjust my Vout using the potentiometer within the range of 2V-3V.

With my current R1 & R2 I am not able to achieve it. How do I calculate the values for R1 and R2 so that I can adjust my output from 2V-3V?

Comment: I suspect that your circuit diagram is incorrect; the voltage source is backwards and one end is open.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a homework question and not real-world- you know the **range** of voltage adjustment, which defines the voltage across VR2's element, and thus the current through VR2.

Once you know the current through VR2 you know the current through R3 and R1 since they are all in series. You then can easily calculate the value of R3 to get the required voltage at the low end of the element and the value of R1 to establish that current.

In the real world, if you wanted guaranteed range of adjustment it would be more complicated and in particular because the tolerance (and tempco) of pot elements tends to be poor in comparison to resistors. So you'd either use lower values for R1/R3 to increase the range or add another resistor to mitigate the effects of VR2.

Answer (score 0):

- You require to have 1 volt across the potentiometer. The potentiometer is 50 kΩ
- The lower voltage on your pot needs to be 2 volts. This means that the lower resistor needs to be 100 kΩ i.e. 1 volt per 50 kΩ
- The upper resistor needs to drop 2 volts across it hence it needs to also be 100 kΩ

<sub>Note - I didn't assume this was a homework question</sub>